# Select text only one line at a time from group of divs

Tags: javascript, angular, html

#### Backdrop

I am trying to select the text inside of one div element at a time from a group of div elements and getting its start and end indices.

I am using the `mouseup` event to capture the selection of the text by the user.

---

#### Current situation

**More than one div element is being selected at a time like in the below attached screenshot.**

[image]

---

#### Expected result

If one div element is selected actively the user should be able to only select that div element after lifting the mouse.

[image]

Like in Google's DialogFlow portal, the user can only select one sentence at one time. For selecting the next sentence he should go to the next row to select it which is illustrated in the below screenshot.

[image]

**This is a part of the application [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx5wmu) which I'm trying to make, which contains as how to reproduce the issue and give a solution.**

I am unable to think of ways of how to acheive this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 1):

You could set the CSS property [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) to `none` on the container of the lines which will prevent text selection altogether, and then on mouse down, enable text selection just on one line.

Resetting the `user-select` property is a little tricky because it will immediately remove a selection, so you actually have to remember which line was selected and reset it on the next mouse down event.

```js
let lastTarget;

function handleMouseDown(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  
  if (lastTarget) {
    lastTarget.style.userSelect = '';
  }
  
  if (target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  
  target.style.userSelect = 'text';
  
  document.onmouseup = function () {
    lastTarget = target;
    document.onmouseup = null;
  }
}

container.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
```

```css
#container {
  user-select: none;
}

#container > div  > span {
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div><span>If one div element is selected actively the user should be able to only select that div element after lifting the mouse.</span></div>
  <div><span>If one div element is selected actively the user should be able to only select that div element after lifting the mouse.</span></div>
  <div><span>If one div element is selected actively the user should be able to only select that div element after lifting the mouse.</span></div>
  <div><span>If one div element is selected actively the user should be able to only select that div element after lifting the mouse.</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the extra span and CSS is to better simulate how the text cursor should behave when hovering over the lines.

Comment: we have to be extra useful while doing this

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the divs will never be equal, do div's text indexOf(selection) it will return false if text from multiple divs is selected.